C Syntax "Semicolon"
  int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf(" %d \n", i);
        }

output:
0
1
2
3
4
   int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++); {
        printf(" %d \n", i);
        }

output:
5
Why is the Semicolon make so different when put it after the for loop

i is set to 5 after the loop

If you put ; after the for(...) it means the body of the loop is empty. See: The Definitive C Book Guide and List.

Because that's what syntax does? They are not, like, decorative semicolons.

In the 1st snippet, the compound statement containing the printf call forms the body of the for loop. In the 2nd snippet, the body of the for loop is an empty statement terminated by the semicolon, and the compound statement containing the printf statement is a separate statement after the for loop statement. (The use of a compound statement in the 2nd snippet is redundant, but they can be useful for restricting the scope of declarations.)

If you defined i in the loop (as in for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)), the second example wouldn't compile because there wouldn't be a variable i in scope unless your original code was hiding another variable i (which would be bad practice).

What makes you think the output of two different program's shouldn't be different?  Or that the magnitude of the difference between the two codes should be correlated with the magnitude of the difference between the outputs?

In your second code snippet you have a semicolon ; after the for loop for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);.

The semicolon signifies the end of the statement and results in an empty body.
In each interation i++, but body is empty due to ;, so nothing happens.
i becomes 5, causing loop to terminate.


; indicates the end of the statement. If the statement body is missing then it is called an empty statement. Statement can also contain many statements enclosed in { }
for loop structure:
for (initialization; condition; iteration) statement;

If you place the ; just after the for loop closing ) the statement will be empty. The compound statement after the semicolon is not part of the for loop.
It is a very common source of bugs in C language. If you accidentally add a semicolon after the loop header when you intended to have a block of code, it can lead to unintended behaviour (as in your example):
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++); 
        {
             printf(" %d \n", i);
        }


Tip: Use an auto formatter.  Saves times, makes for a better presentation too.
Using my Eclipse IDE
int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++); {
        printf(" %d \n", i);
        }

Became:
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    ;
  {
    printf(" %d \n", i);
  }

And from there it is easier to see the printf() is not part of the for() loop.  The loop simple incremented i several times and then 5 was printed.

The syntax is
for ( ... ) STMT

A curly-delimited block is a statement.
for ( ... ) { }

But so is an expression followed by a semi-colon.
for ( ... ) printf( ... );

And so is just a semi-colon.
for ( ... );

This is what you have. You're executing an empty statement 5 times, having no effect but changing i.

The following is a cleaned-up version of your second snippet:
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   /* Do nothing */;

{
   printf(" %d \n", i);
}

It's equivalent to this:
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   /* Do nothing */
}

printf(" %d \n", i);

And it's thus equivalent to this:
int i = 5;
printf(" %d \n", i);


A small note for the OP: if the variable i was scoped locally to the loop, the second example would have prompted an error. Not being able to see the full code, there may be a reason not to do this, of course.

When you put a semicolon, it finishes the code, so when you put after parenthesis you finish the for loop and then print the last 'i', that is 5.
